# Difficulty in setting up SMTP on my server

Tags: smtp, email

I'm setting up my server for the first time and I've run into an issue in trying to send mail using SMTP. As per the suggestion of a few answers on SF, I've used [SMTPDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=bc1881c7-925d-4a29-bd42-71e8563c80a9&displaylang=en) to try and diagnose the issue and it seems the issue is 'Failed to connect to the domain controller. Error: 8007054b'.

Can anyone help me to make sense of this error?

```
Searching for Exchange external DNS settings.
Computer name is XXX.
Failed to connect to the domain controller. Error: 8007054b

Checking SOA for gmail.com.
Checking external DNS servers.
Checking internal DNS servers.
SOA serial number match: Passed.

Checking local domain records.
Checking MX records using TCP: gmail.com.
Checking MX records using UDP: gmail.com.
Both TCP and UDP queries succeeded. Local DNS test passed.

Checking remote domain records.
Checking MX records using TCP: gmail.com.
Checking MX records using UDP: gmail.com.
Both TCP and UDP queries succeeded. Remote DNS test passed.

Checking MX servers listed for XXX@gmail.com.
Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.77.27] on port 25.
Successfully connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Connecting to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.127.27] on port 25.
Successfully connected to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Connecting to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.95.27] on port 25.
Successfully connected to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Connecting to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.157.27] on port 25.
Successfully connected to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Connecting to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.91.27] on port 25.
Successfully connected to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following for a detailed walk-through on your output - http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2004/09/28/14480.aspx. Based on the information contained within the blog, you may be perfectly fine...

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Comment: Page not found, please update the url and better to paste the important content here.